Recursively fill dates in dplyr mutate
Suppose you have
aa <- tibble(date = ymd(c('20240101','20240102',NA, NA, NA)))

How do you fill the NA values using the dplry mutate statement?
This does not work.  It only fill the first NA value.
library(lubridate)
aa %>% 
  mutate(date = if_else(!is.na(date), date, dplyr::lag(date) + lubridate::days(1)))


Are the set dates guaranteed to be sequential and without gaps? Or is there a chance to encounter something like tibble(date = ymd(c('20240101','20240103','20240104', NA, NA, '20240110'))) ?

mutate(aa, date = seq.Date(first(date), first(date) + n() - 1, 1)) might be the easiest.

Here's one way:
aa |>
  group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(date))) |>
  mutate(
    date = first(date) + row_number() - 1
  ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 5 × 1
#   date      
#   <date>    
# 1 2024-01-01
# 2 2024-01-02
# 3 2024-01-03
# 4 2024-01-04
# 5 2024-01-05


We can use accumulate (or Reduce from base R) to iterate over date with the anonymous function shown.  Here y is the current date and x is the previous value of the function.  coalesce returns its first non-NA argument.
library(purrr)
aa %>%
  mutate(date = accumulate(date, \(x, y) coalesce(y, x + 1)))

Other approaches are possible if we can make additional assumptions.  If we knew that the dates always increase by 1, i.e. no gaps, then we can find the index, i, of the first non-NA date and use that:
aa %>% {
  i <- which.min(is.na(.$date))
  mutate(., date = date[i] + row_number() - i)
}

If, in addition, we knew that the first date is not NA then i must be 1 so it simplifies to
aa %>%
  mutate(date = first(date) + row_number() - 1)

Note
The input used:
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

aa <- tibble(date = ymd(c('20240101','20240102',NA, NA, NA)))

